# How to estimate the linearity of this servo from its datasheet

Tags: servo

What parameters indicate to what extent the steps are evenly distributed over a rotation? 
Is there such a parameter which indicates that kind of linearity of a servo motor?

--to be updated--

Comment: According to the datasheet the encoder has 1024 pulses per rotation. No spec is given for encoder linearity, but it _should_ be significantly better than the angle between pulses (0.35º).

Answer (score 1):

For most applications of stepper motors the step size is assumed to be perfectly linear, or 'good enough' as the variability in step size for a well constructed stepper will in general be very small. If you're really concerned, you could test it out yourself with a magnetic encoder (such as the KMZ60) and diametrically magnetized magnet.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't stepper motors, they're brushless servo motors with [quadrature encoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_encoder#Quadrature_outputs) as feedback. Instead of a series of coils which energize and move the motor in fixed steps, you have a brushless motor with a feedback mechanism that reports the position and direction by providing pulses as two square waves 90° apart. In order to control the number of rotations, you will probably need to use a [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller). Basically such a controller will drive the motor using PWM and utilize the feedback to "know" how much to speed up or slow down to achieve the desired position or number of rotations, etc.